# Is the force applied on a ferrous object by a magnetic field determined by the field strength or its derivative?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

One scenario for visualizing this question is a steel ball inside a finite solenoid. When doing that experiment myself, I notice that the ball will always roll towards the center, but the force on the ball seems to do down as it gets closer to the center.

Therefore, I wonder if the force applied on ferrous objects is defined by the derivative with respect to position of the field, or by the strength of the field itself. Does anybody have insight as to the relationship between attraction force on ferrous objects and field strength?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both.

The field gradient (derivative) generates a translational (moving) force on the ball directed towards a region of higher field strength. This is used e.g. for magnetic tool bits or connectors. If the ball was not steel but a diamagnetic medium, it would be pushed away from regions with high magnetic field (search for "levitating frog").

In addition the local field vector itself will also generate force on objects that have some anisotropy and apply rotational force (torque) on them to align their long side along the field vector. This is exploited for compass needles. A spherical ball won't experience torque unless it has internal axes that are more easily magnetizable than others.